# Can a RemoteViews be passed in an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am trying to pass a RemoteViews to an `intent` so I can use it later on to update my Notification. However, the RemoteViews always comes out null when getting it from the Intent.

Basically, on a button click the `Notification` will either decrease or increase the weight value displayed as a `textview` in the notification.

```
RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.remote_view_exercise_workout);
Intent addWeightIntent = new Intent(context, ExerciseWorkoutNotification.class);
addWeightIntent.putExtra("expandedView", expandedView);
expandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.UpWeightButton, PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, addWeightIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

And Then on the intent handling :

```
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent)  
RemoteViews expandedView = (RemoteViews) intent.getSerializableExtra("expandedView");
updateWeightNotification(workout, expandedView, workoutPosition, operator);
```

However, my expandedView always comes out null on the intentHandle.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RemoteViews expandedView = (RemoteViews) intent.getParcelableExtra("expandedView");
```

Edit: Since `RemoteViews` is implementation of `Parcelable`, the above solution should work.

Comment: Always add explanations to answers. Just as questions needs to be clear, so do answers.